# TYPO3 sys_catecory

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I am using TYPO3 10 and the news extension. My news page is separatet into four tabs that uses the category as tab name. I try to output the category, e.g. tab name if is current selected and want to output as title in the title-tag by using typoscript, how can I do that?

This is my current TypoScript:

```
[page["uid"] == 6]

lib.categoryTitle = CONTENT
lib.categoryTitle {
    if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    select {
        uidInList.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        pidInList = 57
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON tx_news_domain_model_news.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
        orderBy = sys_category.sorting
        max = 1
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = title
        htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }
}

page = PAGE
page {
  headerData {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      field = title
      noTrimWrap = |<title>News zu: | </title>|
    }
  }
}

page.headerData.10 =
page.headerData.10 < lib.categoryTitle
```

[END]

Comment: What is your output currently?

Comment: The current output in the title-tag is the url of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the type of `page.headerData.10` while copying: `page.headerData.10 < lib.categoryTitle`.  So it's a `CONTENT`-cobject now, which does not have *stdWrap*-data type. So the `noTrimWrap` is not taken into account anymore.

But it has a *stdWrap*-property: move the wrap to `page.headerData.10.stdWrap.noTrimWrap`. Then, there will be a title-tag again, and the browser won't default to the URL.

---

Update 2022-03-17:

With the copy of `lib.categoryTitle` applied and the above modification, it should evaluate as TypoScript:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  headerData {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
      field = title
      stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |<title>News zu: | </title>|
      
      if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      table = tx_news_domain_model_news
      select {
        uidInList.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        pidInList = 57
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON tx_news_domain_model_news.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
        orderBy = sys_category.sorting
        max = 1
      }

      renderObj = TEXT
      renderObj {
        field = title
        htmlSpecialChars = 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`field` is no property of `CONTENT`, so it should be ignored and output can't be "News zu: 'Pagetitle'"

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for your quick reply, your description helped me a step forward. I changed it as you described, now I have an output: News zu: 'Pagetitle', but I do not have any output of categories. Why does lib.categoryTitle not work?

Comment: Sure, your code above is complete? Or is something missing/wrong due to simplification?